# Find max and min ratios of two angles during rotation of a square

Tags: geometry

$\square AEFG $ and $\square ABCD$ share the same corner A, $AE=\frac{1}{2}AB$. If we rotate $\square AEFG $ around A by $\alpha$ , $\frac{\angle ECF}{\angle GCF}=1$ when $\alpha = 0^\circ$ and $180^\circ$. By intuition, the ratio should reach a max and min value  somewhere between these two angles.   I am trying to figure out  these max and min angle ratios and corresponding rotation angles. I think we  can set up coordinates of E,F,G,C based upon the rotation angle $\alpha$ first and then explore the solution by calculation,  but is there a simple geometry way to solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively, at some point $C,F,G$ lies on the same line, so does $E,F,C$ at another point.

You can find exactly when these happen via trigonometry.

For example, when $C,F,G$ are collinear, $AG \perp GC$ with $\dfrac {AG}{GC} = \dfrac 1{2\sqrt2} = \cos\angle CAG$.

The angle $\alpha$ when this happens is $\cos^{-1}\left(\dfrac1{2\sqrt2}\right) - 45^\circ \approx 24.3^\circ$ (anticlockwise).

In these cases the angles are zero, hence the minimum of the ratio is $0$ and there is no maximum.

Answer (score 1):

As far as maximum ratio, the limit is $\infty$. The minimum ratio is $0$. There will be an angle $\alpha$ for which points $C, F$ and $E$ are collinear leading to the minimum ratio of $0$. Similarly, there will be an angle $\alpha$ for which points $C, F$ and $G$ are collinear.

Here is a diagram showing first example for clockwise rotation.

[image]

$\angle CAE = \arccos {\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}}$

$\alpha = \angle CAE - 45^0$ in clockwise direction gives minimum (or subtract from $360^0$ to express in anti-clockwise direction).

If we rotate further by $90^0$ in clockwise direction, we will have points  $C, G$ and $F$ becoming collinear ($G$ in between $C$ and $F$).

We similarly get another two angles when we rotate in anti-clockwise direction.